# Android Studio Build Analyzer - Misc Gradle steps

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

To analyze the speed of my builds, I use Build Analyzer integrated in Android Studio. The build duration is divided into three main parts, but I don't know what exactly the last part contains. The first two parts have a detailed description, but not the last one. Don't you know what is included in the part called Misc Gradle steps? Obviously, it takes most of the time.

[image]